# Let and Property Assignment in one line

Tags: f#, properties, variable-assignment

How can you write the following F# code (or similar) in one line:

```
let contextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip()
mainForm.ContextMenuStrip <- contextMenu
```

I have to declare *contextMenu* as it will be needed later.

Answer (score 6):

I don't recommand you to write it on a single line because this means it will be a mix between the #light (the mode by default now) and non #light syntax. If you really need to, you can use ;; like that:

```
open System
open System.Windows.Forms

let mainForm = new Form()
let contextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();; mainForm.ContextMenuStrip <- contextMenu;;
```

If your expressions have unit type you can use a Sequential Execution Expression, which is an expression of the form:

```
expr1; expr2; expr3
```

for instance:

```
mainForm.ContextMenuStrip <- contextMenu; 5 + 6 |> ignore; mainForm.ContextMenuStrip <- null
```

I'd like to add that Sequential Execution Expressions have nothing to do with the non #light mode. They are just a general language construct.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

You can set public, writeable properties as pseudo-parameters in the constructor.

```
let contextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip()
let form = new Form(ContextMenuStrip = contextMenu)
```

Comment: +1, My guess is that there could be a side effect in the property setter and it scared someone.  I like this syntax.  It encourages people to write small constructors and use properties instead.

Comment: Oh I see, he's setting the value in the Form not the ContextMenuStrip.  So it doesn't answer the question though I still found this answer of use.
let contextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip()
let mainForm = new Form(ContextMenuStrip = contextMenu)

Answer (score 5):

You could also type

```
let contextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip() in mainForm.ContextMenuStrip <- contextMenu
```

This is OCaml syntax, IIRC.

Edit: to be more clear: this is also valid (#light) F# syntax, since F# is based on OCaml.

I also don't recommend doing this, even though I like short programs.